# Is it possible to center a frame in the middle of the screen in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frames

I am a high school student coding in Python and I have a very simple GUI application, and my program is different from others in that it doesn't use normal Tkinter windows. I used frames so that my code would flow more, but now I want to know is it possible to make each frame pop up in the center of my screen and not off to the top left. I am still new to this so let me know if you need anything more. Thank you <3
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk                
from tkinter import font as tkfont

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: did you try to use `frame.pack(anchor = 'center')` ?

Comment: You can use the `geometry` method on the root window to get it to appear anywhere you want.

Comment: I tried both and no luck

Comment: @ChrisBoss Post what you have tried on using `geometry()` function.